# Clean Architecture - Repository is a Gateway? If is right, a usecase can call a Repository directly?

Tags: clean-architecture

We now that, os clean architecture we have a layers and arrow dependence to center, ask this, a usecase can call a Repository directly?

Example:

Usecase:

```
public class SomeRepository{

  DBImplementatio db;

  public String save(String string){

  db.implSave(string);
}

}

public class SomeUsecase{
  SomeRepository repository;
  
  public void doSomething(){
    repository.save("saveMe");
}

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Repository and Gateway are used interchangeably to abstract the API of another service such as a database.

A use case should not call a repository directly. In fact it shouldn't know anything about any concrete repository at all.

The Repository/Gateway should be an interface and must be implemented by the Repository implementation class.

Then, you can inject the Repository implementation instance in the use case constructor(Dependency inversion). This way use case wont depend on the implementation itself but on the abstraction(interface).

```
public interface Repository {
    String save(String string);
}

public class RepositoryImpl implements Repository {
    public String save(String string) {
        // Implementation of save here
    }
}

public class SomeUsecase{
    Repository repository;
    public SomeUsecase(Repository repository) {
        this.repository = repository
    }
    
    public void doSomething(){
        this.repository.save("saveMe");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best option in my opinion is to create a interface for your use case:

```
public interface SomeUsecase{
  void doSomething;
}
```

Then you create a implementation of this interface in the data layer:

```
public class SomeUsecaseImplementation implements SomeUsecase{
  SomeRepository repository;
  
  public void doSomething(){
    repository.save("saveMe");
  }
}
```

This way your data layer is coupled with the repository instead of your use case.